# What functionality do you get for free with Functors or other type-classes?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

I read an [article](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-01-08-streams-coroutines.md) which said:

> Providing instances for the many standard type-classes [Functors] will immediately give you a lot of functionality for practically free

My question is: what is this functionality that you get for free (for functors or other type-classes)? I know what the definition of a functor is, but what do I get for **free** by defining something as a functor/other type-class. Something other than a prettier syntax. Ideally this would be general and useful functions that operate on functors/other type-classes.

My imagination (could be wrong) of what free means is functions of this sort: `TypeClass x => useful x y = ..`

== Edit/Additition ==

I guess I'm mainly asking about the more abstract (and brain boggling) type-classes, like the ones in [this image](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/d/df/Typeclassopedia-diagram.png). For less abstract classes like Ord, my object oriented intuition understands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functors are simple and probably not the best example. Let's look at Monads instead:

- `liftM` - if something is a Monad, it is also a Functor where `liftM` is `fmap`.
- `>=>`, `<=<`: you can compose `a -> m b` functions for free where `m` is your monad.
- `foldM, mapM, filterM`... you get a bunch of utility functions that generalize existing functions to use your monad.
- `when`, <strike>`guard`</strike>* and `unless` -- you also get some control functions for free.
- `join` -- this is actually fairly fundamental to the definition of a monad, but you don't need to define it in Haskell since you've defined `>>=`.
- transformers -- `ErrorT` and stuff. You can bolt error handling onto your new type, for free (give or take)!

Basically, you get a wide variety of standard functions "lifted" to use your new type as soon as you make it a `Monad` instance. It also becomes trivial (but alas not automatic) to make it a `Functor` and `Applicative` as well.

However, these are all "symptoms" of a more general idea. You can write interesting, nontrivial code that applies to *all* monads. You might find some of the functions you wrote for your type--which are useful in your particular case, for whatever reason--can be generalized to all monads. Now you can suddenly take your function and use it on parsers, and lists, and maybes and...

* As Daniel Fischer helpfully pointed out, `guard` requires `MonadPlus` rather than `Monad`.

Comment: `guard` requires `MonadPlus`.

Comment: Since there only seems to be a handful of such library functions, even for monad which is a pretty rich type-class, I'd conclude it is unlikely to happen. It is _theoretically_ possible that your code may magically generalize to all monads, but practically if they existed, I'd see a lot more useful functions for free for monads.

Answer (score 5):

Functors are not very interesting by themselves, but they are a necessary stepping stone to get into applicative functors and [`Traversables`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html).

The main property which makes applicative functors useful is that you can use `fmap` with the applicative operator `<*>` to "lift" any function of any arity to work with applicative values. I.e. you can turn any `a -> b -> c -> d` into `Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f c -> f d`. You can also take a look at [`Data.Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html) and [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) which contain several general purpose functions that involve applicative functors.

[`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) is a specialized applicative functor which supports choice between alternatives that can "fail" (the exact meaning of "empty" depends in the applicative instance). Applicative parsers are one practical example where the definitions of `some` and `many` are very intuitive (e.g. match some pattern zero-or-more times or one-or-more times).

Monads are one of the most interesting and useful type-classes, but they are already well covered by the other answers.

[`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html) is another type-class that is both simple and immediately useful. It basically defines a way to add two pieces of data together, which then gives you a generic `concat` as well as functionality in the aforementioned `Foldable` module and it also enables you to use the [`Writer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Writer.html) monad with the data type.

Answer (score 4):

There are many of the standard functions in haskell that require that their arguments implement one or more type-classes.  Doing so in your code allows other developers (or yourself) to use your data in ways they are already familiar with, without having to write additional functions.

As an example, implementing the Ord type-class will allow you to use things like sort, min, max, etc.  Where otherwise, you would need sortBy and the like.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it means that implementing the type class `Foo` gives you all the other functions that have a `Foo` constraint "for free".

The `Functor` type class isn't too interesting in that regard, as it doesn't give you a lot.

A better example is monads and the functions in the `Control.Monad` module. Once you've defined the two `Monad` functions `(>>=)` and `return` for your type, you get another thirty or so functions that can then be used on your type.

Some of the more useful ones include: `mapM`, `sequence`, `forever`, `join`, `foldM`, `filterM`, `replicateM`, `when`, `unless` and `liftM`. These show up all the time in Haskell code.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, Functor itself doesn't actually get you much for free. Basically, the more high-level or general a typeclass is (meaning the more things fit that description), then the less "free" functionality you are going to get. So for example, Functor, and Monoid don't provide you with much, but Monad and Arrow provide you with a lot of useful functions for free.

In Haskell, it's still a good idea to write an instance for Functor and Monoid though (if your data type is indeed a functor or a monoid), because we almost always try to use the most general interface possible when writing functions. If you are writing a new function that can get away with only using `fmap` to operate on your data type, then there is no reason to artificially restrict that function to to `Monad`s or `Applicative`s, since it might be useful later for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Your object-oriented intuition carries across, if you read "interface and implementation" for "typeclass and instance". If you make your new type C an instance of a standard typeclass B, then you get for free that your type will work with all existing code A that depends on B.

> [image: UML diagram]

As others have said, when the typeclass is something like `Monad`, then the freebies are the many library functions like `foldM` and `when`.